# Why doesn't my navigation bar line up with the sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I've been trying to make a website for my school assignment, and it requires me to make a cinema related website, I've made a navigation bar, and stole a seating arrangement script from online. But when I tried merging the two scripts, the navigation bar just doesn't line up.

How it's supposed to look like:
[Don't worry about the colouring] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IdCr.png)

Versus:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESHFp.png)

It might be a problem with the margin, but I'm no coding expert. Could anyone please help me with this?

Here is the code:

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
    <title>CaboArcade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04f6b9081f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".hamburger").click(function () {
                $(".wrapper").toggleClass("collapse");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top_navbar">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="top_menu">
                <div class="logo">Placeholder Cinema Name</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/1">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/displayGames">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Movies</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/passwordManager">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Careers</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/logout" class="active">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-out"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Logout</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/login">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-in"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Login</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/signup">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Signup</span>
                    </a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>


            </div>
 

    <div class="movie-container">
        <label> Select a movie:</label>
        <select id="movie">
            <option value="30">Godzilla vs Kong ($30)</option>
            <option value="25">Radhe ($25)</option>
            <option value="25">RRR ($25)</option>
            <option value="25">F9 ($25)</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <ul class="showcase">
        <li>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <small>Available</small>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="seat selected"></div>
            <small>Selected</small>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <small>Sold</small>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="screen"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat sold"></div>
            <div class="seat"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text">
        You have selected <span id="count">0</span> seat/s for a price of $<span id="total">0</span>
    </p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper .top_navbar{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

    .wrapper .top_navbar .hamburger {
        width: 70px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #e81717;
        padding: 15px 17px;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .wrapper .top_navbar .hamburger div {
        width: 35px;
        height: 4px;
        background: #ff8080;
        margin: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu {
        width: calc(100% - 70px);
        height: 100%;
        background: #ff8566;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

        .wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu .logo {
            color: #d51515;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul{
  display: flex;
}

    .wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 10px;
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #2e4ead;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #e81717;
    }

        .wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a:hover {
            background: #ff8080;
            color: #fff;
        }

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a:hover i{
  color: #fff;
}

    .wrapper .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        left: 10px;
        background: #e81717;
        width: 200px;
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            color: #ffb3b3;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

            .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 3px;
                height: 100%;
                background: #ffb3b3;
                display: none;
            }

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.icon{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.title{
  display: inline-block;
}

            .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover,
            .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active {
                background: #ff6666;
                color: #fff;
            }

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active:before{
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .main_container{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper .main_container .item{
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar{
  width: 70px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a{
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.icon{
  margin: 10%;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.title{
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.collapse .main_container{
  width: calc(100% - 70px);;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

My JAVASCRIPT:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const seats = document.querySelectorAll(".row .seat:not(.sold)");
const count = document.getElementById("count");
const total = document.getElementById("total");
const movieSelect = document.getElementById("movie");

populateUI();

let ticketPrice = +movieSelect.value;

// Save selected movie index and price
function setMovieData(movieIndex, moviePrice) {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedMovieIndex", movieIndex);
    localStorage.setItem("selectedMoviePrice", moviePrice);
}

// Update total and count
function updateSelectedCount() {
    const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll(".row .seat.selected");

    const seatsIndex = [...selectedSeats].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));

    localStorage.setItem("selectedSeats", JSON.stringify(seatsIndex));

    const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length;

    count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount;
    total.innerText = selectedSeatsCount * ticketPrice;

    setMovieData(movieSelect.selectedIndex, movieSelect.value);
}


// Get data from localstorage and populate UI
function populateUI() {
    const selectedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedSeats"));

    if (selectedSeats !== null && selectedSeats.length > 0) {
        seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
            if (selectedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                console.log(seat.classList.add("selected"));
            }
        });
    }

    const selectedMovieIndex = localStorage.getItem("selectedMovieIndex");

    if (selectedMovieIndex !== null) {
        movieSelect.selectedIndex = selectedMovieIndex;
        console.log(selectedMovieIndex)
    }
}
console.log(populateUI())
// Movie select event
movieSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    ticketPrice = +e.target.value;
    setMovieData(e.target.selectedIndex, e.target.value);
    updateSelectedCount();
});

// Seat click event
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (
        e.target.classList.contains("seat") &&
        !e.target.classList.contains("sold")
    ) {
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");

        updateSelectedCount();
    }
});

// Initial count and total set
updateSelectedCount();
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. The result resembled your "How it's supposed to look like" image where "top_navbar" is flush with "sidebar". It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.